# Laravel storage stops working after deployment on shared hosting

Tags: php, laravel

when i tried to change user profile avatar in localhost its working but when i tried on shared hosting its not working.
please check my homecontroller code

```
  public function upload(Request $request)
    {
        $validatedData = $request->validate([
            'image' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg|max:2048',
           ]);
        if($request->hasFile('image')){
            $filename = $request->image->getClientOriginalName();
            $unique_name = md5($filename. time());
            $request->image->storeAs('images',$unique_name,'public');
            Auth()->user()->update(['image'=>$unique_name]);
        }
        return Redirect('user/profile')->with("success","Profile image successfully changed!");
    }
```

Comment: now i found a manual solution, my image data is going into storage/app/public/images but not going into public/storage/images.. how can i fix this

Answer (score 1):

Your images are going to `storage` by default you can change it to `public` by modifying `config/filesystems.php` like this:

```
'disks' => [
   'public' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root'   => public_path() . '/images', // change this to your desired path
       'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
       'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
]
```

And then access this storage by:

```
Storage::disk('public')->put('filename', $file_content);
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure you have link to your storage, so run this command

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Your images are going to storage by default you can change it to public by modifying config/filesystems.php like this:

'disks' => [
   'public' => [
       'driver' => 'local',
       'root'   => public_path() . '/images', // change this to your desired path
       'url' => env('APP_URL').'/public',
       'visibility' => 'public',
    ]
]
```